# Activity Operations in Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on `android activity life-cycle`. But i have a problem with connections.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    speedValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed_value);
    rpmValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rpm_value);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle input = intent.getExtras();

    displayOperations(input);
    super.onResume();
}

public void displayOperations(Bundle input){

    boolean flag = input.getBoolean("flag");
    if(flag){
        for (int i = 0; i < input.getStringArrayList("second").size(); i++) {
            rpmValue.setText(input.getStringArrayList("rpm").get(i));
            speedValue.setText(input.getStringArrayList("speed").get(i));
        }
    }
}

//Menünün içeriği burada ayarlanır.
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case R.id.load_button:
            intent = new Intent(this, Operations.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            onStop();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In this code im tying to get information from other activity. have to go that class and do some operations then come to our main class to be success. Our bundle comes from other activity as you see. There problem occurs right here. My bundle comes null because i couldnt go to second activity.

When i try onResume, application crushes because of null pointer. How can i solve this issue

### LOGCAT

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)'
     on a null object reference
         at com.akaydin.berkin.carmonitor.MainActivity.displayOperations(MainActivity.java:42)
        at com.akaydin.berkin.carmonitor.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:36)
```

Comment: try out these on onResume

Comment: When i try onResume, application crashs instantly

Comment: what is the log says?

Comment: Please use code formatting instead of an screenshot of it. Also, if you post the logcat output it would be helpful.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.akaydin.berkin.carmonitor.MainActivity.displayOperations(MainActivity.java:42)
                                                                                   at com.akaydin.berkin.carmonitor.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:36)

Comment: Hint: `intent.getExtras();` has returned null

Comment: also post the activity code which starts this activty

Answer (score 0):

This is normal.

getIntent() only returns the starting intent, not the one when resuming

So you have several options:

1. **You use a static class :**
   Where you temporarly store the data and access it then from the other class
2. **You call onNewIntent() :**
   You use onNewIntent, which is called before onResume, to ovveride the older intent and replace it by a new one

   `@Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       // getIntent() should always return the most recent
       setIntent(intent);
   }`

   Then you keep the code you have.

As you already did some code, best option for you is the 2. So just add the code somewhere in the main class :)

Hope this helped :)